# Extrapolating (converting) data based on Min and Max values

Tags: matlab, statistics, data-analysis

I have a column vector (not evenly spaced) of size 10000 x 1, with a range of 1 to 7. I want to set new min and max values (min = 32,  max = 72) and extrapolate the vales in between so previous values (1 to 7) now are within the new range (32 to 72).

Comment: I'm a little unclear on your question.  Suppose you have a vector `[1 4 7]` do you want the new vector to be `[32 20/3 72]`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. but the values in my vector are not evenly spaced or ordered in any fashion.

Comment: 20/3 is not between 32 and 72

Comment: Thanks Dan, Smash's ans worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = 7*rand(10000,1);

B = (A-1)/6*(72-32)+32;
```

or in general:

```
minVal = 32;
maxVal = 72;

B = (A-min(A(:)))/(max(A(:))-min(A(:)))*(maxVal-minVal)+minVal;
```

Comment: try it on the value 1. And you don't need to specify element-wise operators here.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
old = [1 4 7];
new = (old - 1)/(7-1)*(72-32) + 32
```

result:

```
new =
    32    52    72
```

Seems too easy, am I missing something? The example of turning 4 into 20/3 above makes me think that I am!